# fdisk says that some head is greater than 16

Tags: fdisk, partition-table

On a virtual machine, I run fdisk and I get:

```
fdisk /dev/vda
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Orden (m para obtener ayuda): p

Disk /dev/vda: 53.7 GB, 53686435840 bytes, 104856320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Identificador del disco: 0x0008c95b

Disposit. Inicio    Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/vda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/vda2         1026048   104856319    51915136   8e  Linux LVM

Orden (m para obtener ayuda): v
Partition 1: head 222 greater than maximum 16
Remaining 2047 unallocated 512-byte sectors
```

I've found that too if I change to cylinders:

```
Disposit. Inicio   Comienzo      Fin      Bloques  Id  Sistema
/dev/vda1   *           3        1018      512000   83  Linux
/dev/vda2            1018      104025    51915136   8e  Linux LVM
```

I know that CHS thing is deprecated but I wonder if such a messages are really errors, and if so, how could I fix it?

### Update 1

gdisks says:

```
gdisk -l  /dev/vda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. 
***************************************************************


Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Disk /dev/vda: 104856320 sectors, 50.0 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 7AB60D44-02EA-48D3-86C2-22104DB8299B
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 104856286
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1026047   500.0 MiB   8300  Linux filesystem
   2         1026048       104856319   49.5 GiB    8E00  Linux LVM
```

Comment: what says gdisk?

Comment: @alecxs I've updated with gdisk info, but AFAIK is unrelated with the fdisk message, correct me if I'm wrong but gdisk warning it's about of an eventual MBR to GPT conversion.

Comment: anyway the conversation looks fine, guess fdisk can't detect 2048 block size? i don't know LVM maybe you can just ignore this